# ReactJS Hamburger icon not toggling

Tags: reactjs, bulma

I am using this library for front end which is based on `Bulma` and I'm facing issues with Hamburger Icon Here is the documentation [Example](https://couds.github.io/react-bulma-components/?selectedKind=Navbar&selectedStory=Default&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybooks%2Fstorybook-addon-knobs&background=%233b5998), but again this is something not very easy to understand. I have searched for a workaround and a solution for this, but I cannot find it, I'm doing it in ES6 Style, and here is my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Navbar } from "react-bulma-components/full";
class MenuNavbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="header">
        <Navbar color="info" fixed="top">
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Item renderAs="a" href="/">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9jQaBuq.png" alt="Dew Ventures" />
            </Navbar.Item>
            <Navbar.Burger />
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Menu>
            <Navbar.Container>
              <Navbar.Item href="/">Home</Navbar.Item>
              <Navbar.Item href="/about"> About Us</Navbar.Item>
              <Navbar.Item href="/contact"> Contact Us</Navbar.Item>
            </Navbar.Container>
          </Navbar.Menu>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuNavbar;
```

Comment: Are you testing on a mobile? According to the documentation it only shows up on a mobile device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Navbar.Burger
     active={open}
     onClick={() =>
       this.setState(state => {
         open: !state.open;
       })
     }
 />
```

From the Storybook you linked to, the example shows that there is an `onClick` handler that sets the state to change the hamburger into a cross.  You need to have some kind of handler that sets the `active` prop to `true`.  That will change the hamburger to a cross whenever you click the component.

And from the [source code of that library](https://github.com/couds/react-bulma-components/blob/master/src/components/navbar/components/burger.js) for the burger component within the `Navbar` that you're using, the component requires you to pass in the active prop as true to set the `is-active` css class, which Bulma uses natively to change the hamburger to a cross:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Navbar } from "react-bulma-components/full";
class MenuNavbar extends Component {
  // set active state for hamburger
  state = { active : false }

  handleClick = () => { 
     const { active } = this.state;
     this.setState({ active: !active }); 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="header">
    <Navbar color="info" fixed="top" active={this.state.active}>
          <Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Item renderAs="a" href="/">
              <img src="https://i.imgur.com/9jQaBuq.png" alt="Dew Ventures" />
            </Navbar.Item>
            <Navbar.Burger
              active={this.state.active}
              onClick={this.handleClick}
    />
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Menu>
            <Navbar.Container>
              <Navbar.Item href="/">Home</Navbar.Item>
              <Navbar.Item href="/about"> About Us</Navbar.Item>
              <Navbar.Item href="/contact"> Contact Us</Navbar.Item>
            </Navbar.Container>
          </Navbar.Menu>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuNavbar;
```

Comment: that crossed my mind earlier, can you be more elaborate on the handler?

Comment: I made an edit to your code to try to incorporate a click handler.  Let me know if that works out at all.

Comment: that's generous of you to write the code, but I'm afraid it is not working, 
`Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `active`.

If you want to write it to the DOM, pass a string instead: active="false" or active={value.toString()}.

If you used to conditionally omit it with active={condition && value}, pass active={condition ? value : undefined} instead.`

This is the stack trace

Comment: @tIm few questions, why `onClick = {this.handleClick}` is not `onClick = {this.handleClick.bind(this)` why are you setting `const {active}`?

Comment: The arrow syntax used in the Component definition allows you to create bound methods without having to use the .bind(this) syntax.  And, I used `const { active }` to get the current state before setting it to the opposite of what it is now.  I'm working on a solution to the problem you identified with the stack trace.  I am having the same problem myself.  I will see what I can do to figure it out.

Comment: but setting it `const` won't allow you to change the state?

Comment: I've got a working example going on my machine.  I'm posting it as an edit to my answer now.

Comment: you forgot to add this `<Navbar color="info" fixed="top" active={this.state.active}>`

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle navbar in pure Bulma CSS with ref usage:

```
burger = React.createRef();
menu = React.createRef();

toggle = () => {

  if (this.menu.current.classList.contains("is-active")) {
    this.menu.current.classList.remove("is-active");
  } else {
    this.menu.current.classList.add("is-active");
  }

};
```

this approach adopted also for your case

Answer (score 0):

Plug and Play React usag utilizing UseEffect...
Remember to add the nav-toggle and navbar-menu classes to your burger and nav respectively

```
  useEffect(() => {
(function() {
  var burger = document.querySelector('.nav-toggle');
  var menu = document.querySelector('.navbar-menu');
  burger.addEventListener('click', function() {
      burger.classList.toggle('is-active');
      menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
  });
 })();
}, [])



        <nav className="navbar">
          <div className="navbar-brand is-1">
            <a href="/" className="navbar-item">
              <img src={logo} alt="YMCA"/>
            </a>
            <button className="navbar-burger burger is-white button nav-toggle"
            aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="Options">
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
              <span></span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div  className="navbar-menu is-8 is-offset-a" id="Options">
            <div className="navbar-end mt-2">
              <button type="submit">Association Level Prediction</button>
              <button type="submit" >Custom Prediction</button>
              <button type="submit" onClick={() => handleNavigate(ROUTE_ABOUT)} className={checkIfActive(ROUTE_ABOUT)}>About</button>
              <button type="submit" onClick={() => handleLogout()} className={checkIfActive('logout')}>Logout</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </nav>
```